# Why is $P(X>r)=q^r$?

Tags: probability

I was studying the geometric distribution when I came across a result that I did not understand. If $X$ follows a geometric distribution, where $p=$$probability$ $of$ $success$ and $q=$$probability$ $of$ $failure$, why is $P(X>r)=q^r?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it means that you have failed for at least the first $r$ times.

Since the only sequence that has this outcome is the one when you always fail, and you fail $r$ times with probability $q$, you have $P(X > r) = q^r$

**Edit**

Okay let's compute $P(X = r+1) + \dots + P(X = n)$

We have

$$pq^{r} + \dots + pq^{n-1} = pq^r(1 + \dots + q^{n-r-1}) = (1-q)q^r \frac{q^{n-r}-1}{q-1} = q^r(1 - q^{n-r}) = q^r - q^{n}$$

Now letting $n \to \infty$ you can see that $q^n \to 0$, so

$$P(X > r) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(X = r+1) + \dots + P(X=n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} q^r - q^n = q^r$$

Comment: I still don't understand. From how I see it, $q^r$ gives the probability that we failed for the fist $r$ times. But if we want the probability the we failed $at least$ $r$ times, wouldn't that be given by $p$ $q^r$ + $q^{r+1}$$p$+ $q^{r+2}$$p$....+ $q^{r+n}$$p$ ?

Comment: It is the same thing.. You can see that  $P( X > r) = P(X=r+1) + \dots + P(X=n)$. Indeed if you factor out the term $q^r$, remember that $p = 1-q$, and remember the formula $1 + x + x^2 + \dots + x^n = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ you should be able to see why ;-)

Comment: @user140161 I've edited the post.. I hope it's more clear :)